# Is there a way to disable the 'clear filter' icon in Nattable filter row when there is no filter string?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, nattable

When I click on a filter cell and then move on to a different area in my view without entering a filter string, the 'clear filter' icon is displayed in the cell even when I haven't entered a string. As shown in the Nattable given below, the filter columns having the icon enabled do not have any filter strings entered. Is there a way to explicity disable this behavior in the FilterRowConfiguration?

[Nattable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMJNq.png)

I found a similar behavior in the `_6031_GlazedListsFilterExample` for the first column in that example. However, the other columns in that example do not show the 'clear filter' icon as expected.

Pasting the contents of my FilterRowConfiguration

```
final DefaultIntegerDisplayConverter idc = new DefaultIntegerDisplayConverter();
final DefaultLongDisplayConverter ldc = new DefaultLongDisplayConverter();

                @Override
        public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry)
        {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < propNames.size() ; i++)    
            {
                
                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                        FilterRowConfigAttributes.TEXT_MATCHING_MODE,
                        TextMatchingMode.REGULAR_EXPRESSION, DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                        FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + i);
                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                        CellConfigAttributes.DISPLAY_CONVERTER,
                        new LinkerMapFilterRowRegexConverter(), DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                        FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + i);

            }
            configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(                                 // comparator
                    FilterRowConfigAttributes.FILTER_COMPARATOR,
                    Comparator.nullsLast(new DefaultComparator()), DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                    FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + propNames
                            .indexOf(ILinkerMapConstants.PROP_KEY_SYMBOL_SIZE));

            configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(                                 // filter display converter
                    FilterRowConfigAttributes.FILTER_DISPLAY_CONVERTER, idc,
                    DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                    FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + propNames
                            .indexOf(ILinkerMapConstants.PROP_KEY_SYMBOL_SIZE));

            configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                    FilterRowConfigAttributes.TEXT_MATCHING_MODE,
                    TextMatchingMode.REGULAR_EXPRESSION, DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                    FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + propNames
                            .indexOf(ILinkerMapConstants.PROP_KEY_SYMBOL_SIZE));
            
            

            configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(                                     // comparator
                    FilterRowConfigAttributes.FILTER_COMPARATOR,
                    Comparator.nullsLast(new DefaultComparator()), DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                    FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + propNames
                            .indexOf(ILinkerMapConstants.PROP_KEY_SYMBOL_ADDRESS));
            
            configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(                                      // filter display converter
                    FilterRowConfigAttributes.FILTER_DISPLAY_CONVERTER, ldc,
                    DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                    FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + propNames
                            .indexOf(ILinkerMapConstants.PROP_KEY_SYMBOL_ADDRESS));
            configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                    FilterRowConfigAttributes.TEXT_MATCHING_MODE,
                    TextMatchingMode.REGULAR_EXPRESSION, DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                    FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + propNames
                            .indexOf(ILinkerMapConstants.PROP_KEY_SYMBOL_ADDRESS));

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should double check if there is really no value in the backing data in the `FilterRowDataProvider`. Debug why the filter icon is displayed. Because it should only show up if a value is set in the backing data.